# Finding the area under a curve represented by the equations $x=a\cos{t}+\frac{a}{2}\ln{\left(\tan^2{\frac{t}{2}}\right)}$ and $y=a\sin t$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

How do I find the area of the curve represented by the following equations,
$$x=a\cos{t}+\frac{a}{2}\ln{\left(\tan^2{\frac{t}{2}}\right)}\\
y=a\sin t$$

Here's what I tried:

Let $A$ denote the area of the curve then $$A=\int y\,dx\\ and\;dx=\left(-a\sin t + \frac{a}{2}\cot {\frac{t}{2}}.\sec^2 {\frac{t}{2}}\right)dt\\So,\;A=\int (a\sin t)\left(-a\sin t + \frac{a}{2}\cot {\frac{t}{2}}.\sec^2 {\frac{t}{2}}\right)dt $$

Now not only does this seem excessively complicated but also I have no idea within which limits should I integrate this expression. Are there any easier alternatives ?

$\mathbf {P.S}$: Also how would one graph this curve ? What would it look like ?

Comment: In your definition of $x(t)$, do you mean $x=a\cos{t}+\frac{a}{2}\ln^2{\left(\tan{\frac{t}{2}}\right)}$ or $x=a\cos{t}+\frac{a}{2}\ln{\left(\tan^2{\frac{t}{2}}\right)}$?

Comment: $x=a\cos{t}+\frac{a}{2}\ln{\left(\tan^2{\frac{t}{2}}\right)}$

Comment: Have made the appropriate corrections.

Comment: You can graph parametric plots on Wolfram Alpha like this: [your curve when a=1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot+%28cos+t+%2B+log%28tan^2%28t%2F2%29%29%2F2%2C+sin+t%29).

Comment: I would try to use the formula $A= \tfrac12 \int (y dx - x dy)$ for the evaluation of the curve...

Answer (score 4):

There are different approaches which lead to the solution. A possibility is to use the symmetric formula
$$ A = \tfrac12 \int \mathbf{r} \times d \mathbf{r} =\tfrac12 \int(y dx - x dy)$$
for the evaluation of the area inclosed by the curve. Plugging in the expressions 
$$ \mathbf{r} = a \bigl[\cos t+\tfrac{1}{2}\ln \tan^2(t/2), \sin t\bigr]^T,$$
$$ d\mathbf{r} = a \cos t \bigl[\cot t, 1 \bigr]^T,$$
 you obtain after some simple transformations
$$A = - \frac{a^2}4 \int_0^{2\pi} \cos t \,\ln \tan^2(t/2) .$$
Integration by parts (integrating $\cos t$ and taking the derivative of the rest), you obtain
$$A= - \underbrace{\frac{a^2}4\sin t \,\ln \tan^2(t/2)\Big|_{t=0}^{2\pi}}_{=0} + \tfrac12 a^2 \int_{0}^{2\pi} dt = \pi a^2.$$

Comment: Brilliant solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: From where would you get that formula? I have never seen it before. Thanks!

Comment: @PranavArora: which formula?

Comment: This one:
$$A = \tfrac12 \int \mathbf{r} \times d \mathbf{r} =\tfrac12 \int(y dx - x dy)$$

Comment: @PravanavArora: I guess you know the formula $A= \int ydx$. If you turn your head (or alternatively the paper) by 90$^\circ$, you find the formula $A= - \int xdy$. Given the two formulas, you can also take the average of them. If you like it more mathematical, you could employ Stokes' theorem.

Comment: @PravanavArora: It is in fact the last formula in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greens_theorem) wiki article.

Comment: The first formula: $A=\int y\,dx$ is obvious, but the second was not obvious to me, thank you for explaining! :) BTW, you misspelled my name twice. :3